# How to make a clear function in python tkinter?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I want to add a clear button in tkinter which clears the text I have entered already and the output. How can I do that?
Here is my code which gets input and provide output using Label.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def myFunction():
    k = myInput.get()
    labl = Label(root,text=k)
    labl.pack()

myInput = Entry(root,width=50, bg="#d2ebd5",borderwidth=5)
myInput.pack()

myButton = Button(root,text="Click me!",command=myFunction)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This should be covered in the documentation for the `Entry` widget. Have you read the documentation? It's not clear why you need our help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `myInput.set("")` to clear Entry var, move `labl` from function to main level, create another function to clear Entry var and `labl` text and button  to run it.